# Mouse randomly stops working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome Classic. Recently, my USB mouse started randomly freezing. The (non-USB) keyboard works fine, so at least I can reboot from the Terminal. What could this be and what can I do?